# How to rollback and stop execution from an inner stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I have two stored procedures, `Outer` and `Inner`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Outer
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET XACT_ABORT ON;

  BEGIN TRAN
    EXEC Inner

    -- Perform additional processing (which should not occur if there is 
    -- a ROLLBACK in Inner)
    ...
  COMMIT
END;
GO
```

The `Outer` stored procedure turns on XACT_ABORT and starts an explicit transaction. It then calls the `Inner` stored procedure inside the transaction.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Inner
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Id INT=(SELECT Id FROM SomeTable WHERE ...);

  IF (@Id IS NOT NULL)
    ROLLBACK;

  INSERT INTO SomeTable(...)
  VALUES (...);
END;
GO
```

The `Inner` stored procedure performs a check to see if something is present and if it is wants to rollback the entire transaction started in the `Outer` stored procedure and abort all further processing in both `Inner` and `Outer`.

The thing that happens instead of what I expect as outlined above, is that I get the error message:

In Inner:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of
>   BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

In Outer:

> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Clearly, the `ROLLBACK` even with XACT_ABORT turned on does not stop the flow of execution. Putting a `RETURN` statement after the `ROLLBACK` gets us out of `Inner`, but execution in `Outer` continues. What do I need to do in order to cause the `ROLLBACK` to stop all further processing and effectively cause an exit out of `Outer`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but what if you did a RAISERROR in the Inner procedure, instead of rollback? I think it should cause the calling transaction to rollback.

Comment: Did it meet ur requirements ?

Answer (score 1):

Issuing the rollback does not abort the batch (Regardless of the XACT_ABORT setting). The batch will automatically abort in your case if an error is thrown with the high enough severity - either system or custom generated via RAISERROR.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `Exception Handling`

```
Begin Try
    Set NOCOUNT ON
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    Begin Tran
        --Your Code
    Commit Tran
End Try

Begin Catch
    Rollback Tran
End Catch
```